# Microsoft Graph Booking Businesses DELETE operations failing: 404 Http response code

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Postman to successfully create a booking business using a POST method Http request to:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses.

The request body is like:
{
"DisplayName" : "TEST",
"Email" : "orgmailbox@xxxbuisiness.onmicrosoft.com"
}

The response contains an id.

[image: POST Response]

I am not succeeding when attempting to delete the booking using the REST API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-delete?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
The Id use in the DELETE request is that extracted from the response body when the booking business was created.

I get Response code 404 ("Unkown Error").

[image]

As per the documentation the registered App in Azure AD has the required *Bookings.Manage.All* permissions

[image]

Does anyone know what might be wrong / how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue we had was due to MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication). When we disabled the requirement for MFA for the user, we were able to successfully make the calls to delete the entry using Postman.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem. If you have deleted it, you will get a 404 error when you run the delete again, so please make sure you have deleted it. There may be some delay.

By the way, when you request the api, do not supply a request body for this method, and do not add unnecessary request parameters.

You can use [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) testing.

First delete request：

[image]

Second delete request：

[image]

Comment: I've tried that - it looks like that if the user that the token belongs to is not a Global Admin user (even though the Booking.Manage.All permission is granted), then, it will fail with the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Carl, Thanks for your suggestions. Our issue turned out to be permissions